# Virtualmin enable DKIM with Postfix error: initctl: Unknown job: dkim-milter

Tags: centos, postfix-mta, dkim, webmin

i got following error while installing DKIM in virtualmin on my centos 6.3 server using postfix as a MTA:-
 Enable DomainKeys Identified Mail

Finding virtual servers to enable DKIM for ..
.. found 1 servers

Generating private key in file /etc/dkim.key ..
.. done

Extracting public key from private key in /etc/dkim.key ..
.. done

Setting domain and selector in DKIM filter configuration ..
.. done

Adding DKIM records to DNS domain core1234.links18.org ..
.. added successfully

Enabling DKIM filter at boot time ..
.. done

```
Starting DKIM filter ..
.. start failed : initctl: Unknown job: dkim-milter

DKIM setup failed!
```

Re-starting DNS server ..
.. done

any help will be great

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this myself.
The reason appears to be that the dkim-milter package on CentOS 6 is not using the new upstart init daemon yet (whereas VirtualMin assumes it should be an upstart job because it is detecting the OS as CentOS 6).

To solve this I created this file: **/etc/init/dkim-milter.conf** with the following contents:

```
description "DKIM Milter Job shim for VirtualMin"
author "Raif Atef"
start on runlevel 5
stop on runlevel [!5]

pre-start script
    sh /etc/init.d/dkim-milter start
end script

post-stop script
    sh /etc/init.d/dkim-milter stop
end script
```

This lets Virtualmin control dkim-milter through upstart and passes the check.
The correct solution of course is to report this as a bug to the package maintainers and ask them to convert /etc/init.d/dkim-milter to upstart job format.

I took the code from here: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/14810/from-init-d-to-upstart-is-there-a-bridge

(reference: CentOS 6 started to use Upstart like Ubuntu, but only a few packages are converted to use it)